# Events filtering/deduplication algorithm

Tags: algorithm, events, duplicates

Lets say i have event listener for events to update user state.

State before:

```
{
    email: "old@email.com",
    name: "John"
}
```

**events coming in order:**

```
eventA = {
    fields: ["email"],
    timestamp: 1541531309
    before: {
        email: "old@email.com"
    },
    after: {
        email: "new@email.com"
    }
}
```

---

```
eventB = {
    fields: ["email", "name"],
    timestamp: 1541531310
    before: {
        email: "old@email.com",
        name: "John"
    },
    after: {
        email: "new@email.com",
        name: "Bill"
    }
}
```

---

```
eventC = { // same as A
    fields: ["email"],
    timestamp: 1541531309
    before: {
        email: "old@email.com"
    },
    after: {
        email: "new@email.com"
    }
}
```

Desired state after:

```
{
    email: "new@email.com",
    name: "Bill"
}
```

How can correctly filter events *without*:

1. saving whole event, all events
2. looping over each field/value of events

Some math/hashing/checksum magic?

**P.S.** it is possible to add more information to event itself.

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "filter events?" It's not at all clear what your desired end state is here.

Comment: @JimMischel sorry for that, by "filtering" i mean: *eventB* has `email` field change same as *eventA* - don't apply it, as it already done in *eventA* and not relevant, but apply `name` field change. *EventC* is a duplicate of *eventA*, so avoid it - do nothing.

Comment: And the reason you don't want to loop ever each field/value in the event? Seems like the only way to be sure that you're not re-applying a change would be to check the before and after values of each field.